# How can I change focus if 2 or more notebooks are open?

Tags: notebooks

Having opened and executed a notebook using NotebookOpen and NotebookEvaluate, I want to return the EvaluationNotebook to the foreground

Comment: Ctrl-Tab (OSX: CMD-Tilde)?

Comment: Ctrl+F6 on windows

Answer (score 3):

I think what you're asking for is something like this:

```
nb0 = EvaluationNotebook[]; nb = 
 CreateDocument[
  ExpressionCell[Defer[Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}]], "Input"]];
NotebookEvaluate[nb, InsertResults -> True];
SetSelectedNotebook[nb0];
1 + 1

(* ==> 2 *)
```

This uses [`SetSelectedNotebook`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetSelectedNotebook.html) to restore the initially saved `nb0` as the current notebook after evaluating the new notebook `nb`.